# diff_match_patch google library is not working as expected in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, google-diff-match-patch

I am writing the text change tracking add-in and my code is:

```
   mDiffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch()
   List<Diff> diffList = mDiffMatchPatch.diff_main(OriginalText, ModifiedText);                        
   mDiffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(diffList);
```

Where  Diff  is an object  with two  properties, 'text' and 'operation'

My original text is :

[image]

When I just insert the word 'ice' after 'installer' is shows up as it should:
[image]

But when I highlight 'installer' and type 'ice' on top of it (replacing 'installer' by 'ice' in one operation), it shows incorrectly.
[image]

That is, it takes the first letter of original 'installer' and separates 'i' from 'ce' in 'ice'.

I checked and re-rechecked and my text color rendering is correct. It is the diff_match_match breaks the 'i' from 'ice' in order to match it with the 'i' of 'installer'.

Is there any remedy for this? If not, is there alternative libraries in C# for diff_match_patch?

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by following the guidance on project github page. That is, using the word-based diff function of the diff_match_patch object. You create it by copying line-based function and modifying it per article.